# Is there a function for finding "ends with"

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a function to find from entries in a column that ends with ".5" using vba?

I have a live feed that I take from a html page, in values in column B are float numbers and I want to know if I can use a VBA function to find out how many values are ending with 0.5

Comment: Yes, you can do this.  It will involve a loop through the cells in column B

Comment: Can you share some sample inputs? `0.5` is likely not enough to extrapolate and fully see the problem. Are these strictly numbers? When you say *ending with `0.5`*, do you mean just the `.5` or the `0.5`? The two are not the same. 1.5 & 10.5 will be evaluated different if you want the `0.5`

Comment: Look into what `VBA.Strings.Right$` can do for you... but I'd probably try a math-based approach, rather than an "ends with" string-based one.

Comment: Thanks urdearby for asking this question. All are numerical values only.. the numbers can be 15.5,1345.4,133.2,2465.6,344.5,75.8 etc

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, will try the VBA.Strings.Right$ as you have mentioned but for now Gary's Student has given a solution that I will try first. Thanks once again for the reply

Answer (score 3):

Well without *VBA*:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(RIGHT(B1:B23,2)=".5"))
```

[image]

and with vba, then:

```
Sub dural()
    MsgBox Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(RIGHT(B1:B23,2)="".5""))")
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

The worksheet formula treats column **B** like `Strings`.  and counts how many in column **B** end with *.5*.  This is expressed as an array of *0/1* by the expression within the --().

`SUMPRODUCT()` just adds up this array.

Comment: Wow!!! this is a easy method... Didn't think about it and was trying to get the hard way. Thank you very much again..That was quick!!!

Comment: Another Excel formula you could use (also with `SUMPRODUCT`): `=SUMPRODUCT(--(INT(A1:A32)=A1:A32-0.5))`

Comment: Could use a bit more explanation about the rationale; this isn't conventional formula usage.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: #TIL about `--()` ...you're going to have a blast with dynamic arrays! (O365)

Comment: If this were code golf, your VBA would win :)  +1 ! Nice solution, I never remember the `SUMPRODUCT` with the `--()` operator.

Comment: @PeterT  I admit `SUMPRODUCT()` is somewhat slow.  I still think it is under-appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

And *with* VBA, as a user-defined function (UDF):

```
Public Function CountThePointFive(ByRef theArea As Range) As Long
    Dim count As Long
    Dim cell As Variant
    For Each cell In theArea
        Dim value As String
        value = CStr(cell.value)
        Dim integerPart As Long
        integerPart = CLng(Left$(CStr(value), Len(value) - InStr(1, value, ".")))
        If (cell.value - integerPart) = 0.5 Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    CountThePointFive = count
End Function
```